# How to find the index and columns of data in pandas dataframe that meet the condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the data index and column of some data in dataframe which meet my condition.

Assume I have a pandas dataframe, looks like:

```
In [5]: a = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

I want to know the columns and index of data which values > 18:

```
In [7]: a> 18
Out[7]: 
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False   True
4   True   True   True   True   True
```

the expected result is:
(3,4) (4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4)

how shall i get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
res = np.argwhere(a.values > 18)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[3 4]
 [4 0]
 [4 1]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]
 [4 4]]
```

Or [where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where)

```
rows, cols = np.where(a > 18)
res = list(zip(rows, cols))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[(3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

A third alternative could be [nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero).

Comment: `list(zip(*np.where(a>18)))`  +1